# Android multiple button press opens multiple tasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-button, android-dialog

i have an activity which has two buttons , one of them is submit and other is cancel. On click of submit i have an asynctask and on Click of cancel i finish the activity.

Below is the code for my submit button.

```
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(track2data.equalsIgnoreCase("null")|| track2data == null){
                track2data = mag.sGetTrack2Data();
            }
            btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);
            btnSubmit.setClickable(false);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
            btnCancel.setClickable(false);
            //changes made by akshay wrt #11983 as on 29 July 2015
            int checkconditions = conditions.checkConditions(edtPin,mContext,verifiedFinger,enterPin,verifyFinger);
            if (track2data != null && track2data.length() > 0
                    && !edtPin.getText().toString().equals("")&& checkconditions == 00) {
                  isoMsgRequest = fintransprovider.getBalanceTransaction(
                            track2data, edtPin.getText().toString());

                MessageAdaptor msgadpt = new MessageAdaptor(mContext);
                ISOMsg rIsoMsg;
                msgadpt.execute(isoMsgRequest);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**MessageAdaptor** is the name of my **asynctask**.

Below is the code for my Cancel button

```
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
        }

    });
```

Whenevr i press these two buttons simultaneously **both the task are performed** i.e i exit my activity(cancel) as well as i run into my asynctask(submit) .
As my **asynctask has a progress dialog** after it finishes its process it just crashes as it gets the **error no window attached**. can ny1 help me.?

Comment: did you try my code ?

Comment: yes i did but no success..

Comment: what is the issue now?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the AsyncTask is not cancelled in `onPostExecute(result)` like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(result) {
       if (!isCancelled()) {
           if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
               mDialog.dismiss();
           }          
       }
    }
```

The issue is your activity is killed before AsyncTask finishes so AsyncTask does not find activity which started it after completing the task.

Answer (score 0):

onPostExcute check whether your activity being killed

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(result) {

       if (!getActivity().isFinishing() && mDialog != null) {
           mDialog.dismiss();
       }          

}
```